# Manipulate of Region Plot

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics

I try to illustrate a generation of an [amoeba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amoeba_(mathematics))  to a [tropical curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_geometry), namely.

```
r0 = ComplexExpand[region["Line"] = ImplicitRegion[x + y + 1 == 0, {x, y}], {x, y}];
f = {Log[t, Abs[Indexed[#, 1]]], Log[t, Abs[Indexed[#, 2]]]} &;
r1 = TransformedRegion[r0, f];
Manipulate[ ParametricRegion[r1, t], {t, 100, 1000, 10}]
```

Unfortunately, I don't get the result. 
How I can improve my code to get the illustration?

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
region["Line"] = ImplicitRegion[x + y + 1 == 0, {x, y}];
r0 = ComplexExpand[region["Line"], {x, y}];
f[t_] := {Log[t, Abs[Indexed[#, 1]]], Log[t, Abs[Indexed[#, 2]]]} &;
r1[t_] := TransformedRegion[r0, f[t]];
Manipulate[RegionPlot[r1[t]], {t, 100, 1000, 10}]
```

Comment: I get the following:
      Tag Function in ({Log[t,Abs[Indexed[#1,1]]],Log[t,Abs[Indexed[#1,2]]]}&)[t_] is Protected.

Comment: Could it be that you have multiple definitions of the same object causing this issue? You could try to clear the global context using `Clear["Global`*"]` and re-run the code above. Alternatively you could try to restart Mathematica.

Comment: Dear Andreas! 
Thank you for you help but I get something strange result:
"{ParametricRegion[{{Log[Abs[x]]/Log[100],Log[Abs[y]]/Log[100]},1+x+y=\
=0},{x,y}][100]} is not a valid region to plot."

Comment: I've just copy-paste your code and don't get any picture, I only get following: 
"AspectRatio->1 is not a valid variable."
"ParametricRegion called with 1 argument; 2 arguments are expected. "
"ParametricRegion is not a Graphics primitive or directive"
" {ParametricRegion[{{Log[Abs[x]]/Log[100],Log[Abs[y]]/Log[100]},1+x+y==0},{x,y}][100]} is not a valid region to plot"

Comment: The code I posted above works fine in Mathematica 10.1. I did not fix the aspect ratio, I only made minimal changes. So, if you start Mathematica, open a new notebook and copy-paste the code above it does not produce the plots?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the case: I create a new notebook and copy-paste the code, but, unfortunately no plot, only reports about mistakes. I don't understand why it is so.
Could you upload the picture you get, please ?

Comment: And you made sure that there are no multiple definitions in the sense of your first comment? What version of Mathematica are you running? If you restart Mathematica, open a new notebook, copy-paste the code above and execute it, what is the first error message that you get? Is it the one with the aspect ratio? I will upload the picture in a sec. If it is ok for you we could continue this discussion in a chat.

Comment: Dear Andreas! 
After restarting everything starts work!!! 
Thank you a lot!!!